# How to disable a collection_select dropdown in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible to have the collection_select dropdown be unclickable(disabled)? I would like the collection_select to initially have a selection displaying but be disabled and then when some other button is clicked, the collection_select is re-enabled again(via javascript) and user can now scroll through the dropdown and click on something else. I tried :disabled => true like in the following but this did not work for me:

Embedded ruby in my html

```
<%=
    collection_select(
        :post,
        :post_name,
        Post.all,
        :post_name,
        :post_name,
        {:selected => Post.where(:p_address => @parentpost.p_address).select("post_name").first.post_name,
        },
        {:id=>'post_collection_select',
         :onchange => "DoStuff(this.value); return false;",
         :autocomplete => "off",
         :disabled => true
        }
     )
%>
```

So far adding the :disabled => true does nothing for me. The collection_selection is behaving exactly as it was before which is the following: it displays many post names in the drop down and one is selected based on the ActiveRecord query provided

Comment: When yo say some other button what other button is this your referring to. Do you want to re-enable it when you have filled in a previous field

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
:disabled => 'disabled'
```

instead of

```
:disabled => true
```

Then when you want to enable the select box use the following jQuery command:

```
$('#post_collection_select').prop('disabled',false);
```

Comment: This will permanently disable the collection_box. But he will need to re-enable this when the prior box has been filled.

Comment: I edited my answer, although I feel like my previous answer fully answered the question "How to disable a collection_select dropdown in ruby"

Comment: your previous answer is correct its understanding what he wants to do with this disabled button. Does he want to re-enable it once the prior field has been field..

Comment: Should have mentioned I had also previously tried :disabled => 'disabled' and this wasn't disabling the collection_box. I've tried it again just in case, in different browsers, still not disabled.